# In Studio is there any way to subtract from a "global" variable?

Tags: jasper-reports

In my case, I have one variable that is `$V{TotalHours}` - these are the hours in which can be used.  Each instance in the report has its own field `$F{Hours}`.  I will need to somehow continuously subtract from `$V{TotalHours}`.

For example:

- Total Hours = 100
- the first record will be 100 - hours
- the second record will be ^that new number - hours
- the third record will be ^that new number - hours
- etc..

kind of confusing.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second variable `$V{SumHours}`. The expression for this variable should be `$F{Hours}` and the type `SUM`.

If your data is shown in the `Detail` band, you can set a text field or another variable to `$V{TotalHours} - $V{SumHours}`. Since the `Detail` band is filled row by row, this calculation would work.

*NOTE:* The variable `$V{TotalHours}` has to be previously filled before using it in the `Detail` band.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! .. Makes sense too now that I think about it.